# How can I reduce my high page reads/sec in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, database, performance, memory, database-performance

I have an extremely high page reads/sec on my SQL Server instance:

[image]

Memory looks good (64GB overall):
[image]

Most blogs/articles online point to increasing RAM but what else can I do to reduce these high page reads/sec?

Comment: The counter is cumulative since the SQL instance was started. Either take a couple of snapshots of the value to calculate the per second value or just use Performance Monitor.

Comment: @DanGuzman - Thanks. I had no idea that value was cumulative. Performance Monitor is showing much better metrics. (Max 4 reads/sec)

Answer (score 1):

Per DanGuzman, the query above is a cumulative count. Use Process Monitor for understanding the actual reads/sec.